# is there a way to access new context api within constructor?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a way to access new context api within constructor?

I want to get context in constructor function, but now i only get after componentDidMount.
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-wave-yy8uq

I try to add the second parameter to constructor function, i can get context in constructor.but I don't know if this is the right way？or is there another way?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-sinoussi-ln7lg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `context` as the second argument and passing it to super is the correct way.

```js
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [jagster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/829493/jagsler) answer. As well I would add that, if you do not use the `props` parameter in the `constructor(props)` and then pass it to `super(props)` it will also be `undefined` in the constructor.